# Retrieve RAR Password through Extracted File

Tags: passwords, hash, file-encryption

So I was wondering about something, but for the simplicity, consider this example:

1. You have a file with *n* encrypted files in it, of which one is called *'Note.txt'*
2. You also happen to have another file (not in the RAR) called *'Note.txt'* which is an exact copy of the file within the RAR, but this is not encrypted!

Is it possible to 'reverse-retrieve' the password used to encrypt the files within the RAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your describing here is a called a [known-plaintext attack (KPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). WinRAR, as old as V3.0, uses AES-128 to encrypt files. As far as we know, AES isn't susceptible to KPAs.

Comment: Short, direct, accurate and answers the question. Thanks!